# Wav files in Windows Media Player queued items not playing correctly at times with C#

Tags: c#, audio, backgroundworker, wav, wmplib

I am doing an application which shows tokens on screen like A0001 Counter 1. Each of the tokens "A","0","0","0","0" "Counter" "1" has wav files stored in a folder ENGLISH in my project as A.wav, 0.wav,0.wav etc. Now I'm using wmplib.dll and running vs 2012 on Win 7 64 bit. I tried using single threading like

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
//my code here
}).Start();
Thread.Sleep(700); //I know this is not a good way to use threads.
```

This code works on Win 7 64 bit perfectly. Now when I try to use it on XP 32 bit the audio sometimes overlaps and sometimes doesn't play. So I used an alternative way using backgroundworker thread. The code is as below.

Issue with this is that the queued items ie. the URL of the files like `C:\project path\ENGLISH\A.wav`, `C:\project path\ENGLISH\0.wav` etc. are queued to the queue and then added to Windows Media player playlist. But they are not playing in order and going off sync at times.

```
public void playAudiofile(String counter_prefix, String counter_name, String token_number)
        {
            String[] token_langs = Config.getTokenLanguages(token_number);

            /*BUZZER*/
            audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir  + "buzzer.wav");

            foreach (String tlang in token_langs)
            {
                String lang = tlang.Trim().ToUpper();
                try
                {
                    if (lang != "NONE")
                    {
                        /*TOKEN*/
                        audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir  + "Token.wav");

                        /*TOKEN NO*/
                        token_number = token_number.ToUpper();
                        char[] tokens = token_number.ToCharArray();
                        foreach (char token in tokens)
                        {
                            if (Char.IsLetter(token))
                            {
                                audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir  + token + ".wav");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir  + token + ".wav");
                            }
                        }
                        /*COUNTER*/
                        counter_prefix = counter_prefix.ToUpper();
                        audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir  + "COUNTER.wav");
                        /*COUNTER NAME*/
                        counter_name = counter_name.ToUpper();
                        char[] counters = counter_name.ToCharArray();
                        foreach (char counter in counters)
                        {
                            if (Char.IsLetter(counter))
                            {
                                audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir + counter + ".wav");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                audio_annoucements.Enqueue(audio_file_dir+ counter + ".wav");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();// i turn off the timer so that backgroundworker can run properly without issues. I turn it on later. 
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
        }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
                String tmpPlaylist = "tmpPlaylist";
                WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist pls;
                WMPLib.IWMPPlaylistArray plItems;
                WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
                plItems = mediaPlayer.playlistCollection.getByName(tmpPlaylist);
                if (plItems.count == 0)
                {
                    pls = mediaPlayer.playlistCollection.newPlaylist(tmpPlaylist);
                }
                else
                {
                    pls = plItems.Item(0);
                    pls.clear();
                }

                while (audio_annoucements.Count > 0)
                {
                    WMPLib.IWMPMedia m1 = mediaPlayer.newMedia(audio_annoucements.Dequeue().ToString());
                    pls.appendItem(m1);
                }
                mediaPlayer.currentPlaylist = pls;
                mediaPlayer.controls.play();

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();// theres a 1 second timer in the form that checks db entries
        }
```

Comment: Adding a question and a note of what goes wrong when trying to run your code could help finding the solution.

Comment: The question and the note both are present. As of now the backgroundworker process needs to be queued since multiple keystrokes cause the media player sounds to play at one time rather than sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute every 700 millisecond try:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(700);
t.Start()
t.Elapsed += (object s1, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e1) => {
                new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
                //my code here
                }).Start();
            };
```